# How do I set an env var for systemd ExecStart command in Linux?

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

I've installed Snapclient on a raspi (a program which receives streaming music and plays it). It has a systemd service file which among others contains this line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snapclient --logsink=system $SNAPCLIENT_OPTS
```

I now want to set the $SNAPCLIENT_OPTS so I added the following line to `/etc/environment`:

```
SNAPCLIENT_OPTS="--host 192.168.178.79"
```

After a reboot and an ssh login as root I see that the env is set:

```
root@dietpi:~# env | grep SNAPCLIENT
SNAPCLIENT_OPTS=--host 192.168.178.79
```

However, the service still doesn't run with that argument:

```
root@dietpi:~# ps aux | grep snap
_snapcl+   525  0.4  1.4  16632  7000 ?        Ss   15:36   0:00 /usr/bin/snapclient --logsink=system
```

In the line above I do see that it isn't run as root though, but as the user `_snapclient`, which explains that the system wide env var isn't picked up. I guess I could set an env var for the user `_snapclient`, but that user doesn't even have a home directory. I can also change the systemd service file, but that seems like a hack.

What would be the correct way to set this env var and have it used when the `snapclient` service is started?

Answer (score 1):

If snapclient.service works this way, it should also have an `EnvironmentFile=` setting that reads from /etc/default, /etc/conf.d, or some similar location. Put your environment variables there.

In case there's no EnvironmentFile specified, use `systemctl edit` to directly add `Environment=` directives to the service:

```
[Service]
Environment=SNAPCLIENT_OPTS="--host 192.168.178.79"
```